# How to push the notification on web browser using django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I create a Todo web application in Django and i deploy it on Heroku. I want to know how can i push the notification in my browser for upcoming task.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multi ways to do so, you can use a for-loop in frontend to query backend internally, or use web socket to push the coming event from backend to frontend.

Comment: Is it possible to push notification using for loop? because notification should be push according the the task time

Answer (score 2):

You should use websockets and async functionality of Django to be able to push realtime notifications as they occur.
Basic http protocol does not give you such functionality.

Comment: It's mean i have to use Django channels for web sockets?

Comment: As Django 3 and above have async views functionality you can implemet it with only websockets. More details here https://dev.to/alexoleshkevich/websockets-in-django-3-1-532o