# Is there a way to update a webpage after it is loaded in django without doing a periodic check?

Tags: javascript, django, htmx

I'm trying to do something similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286850/django-update-a-value-in-html-page-without-refreshing-the-page). Basically, I want to have the html page being updated once new information arrives at the server. The information won't come periodically, but rather in bursts. Is there a way for me to trigger the javascript/htmx function via django or is it that I have to do the per-X-seconds check on the browser side?

All solutions that I've found are using the periodic check in a script which appears a bit surprising to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995/is-there-some-way-to-push-data-from-web-server-to-browser#20004

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259563/how-to-push-the-notification-on-web-browser-using-django

Comment: Seems like you're looking for SSE solution - https://htmx.org/docs/#sse